# Jasper Collection Parameter

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that uses a Collection parameter with the $X variable and everything worked fine.  I designed and published the report, and it worked.  If elements were entered into the collection then the query would filter on those elements.  If no elements were entered into the collection then the collection wouldn't filter anything.

Now I have make a change to the report, but now if no elements are entered into the collection filters everything.  The only thing I can think of that changed between the initial publishing and now is that I've upgraded Jaspersoft Studio to version 6.4.3.  Can anyone else verify my problem, or am I just doing something stupid?

Query below:

```
select mshrid
, msdrmy
, mshet1
, mshet2
, (rownumber() over(partition by mshrid order by dsbtch) - 1)/3 as groupnum
, dsbtch
from finshrm
inner join finshrd on mshrid = dsmshr
where mshrid = $P{id}
and $X{IN, dsbtch, batches}
order by msdrmy, mshet1, mshet2, mshrid, groupnum
```

Comment: The query looks good. Looks like you are passing parameters wrong. You can check parameters with textField, for example

Comment: Are you sure when no elements passed to parameter it shows nothing ? As per jasper collection parameter, if you wont pass anything it will skip that condition and show all the result.